# Sheet copy -> Tahoma switches to Calibri

Tags: excel

I wrote an Excel add-in in VBA. It copies a sheet from the add-in document to the active document (among other tasks). I am using Excel 2013.

Initially the add-in was an XLAM, but that raised an error when the target document is an XLS (number of lines in sheet).

So I saved the add-in as XLA to avoid that issue, and that works fine with both XLS and XLSX targets, EXCEPT for presentation: the text formatting the source XLA is **Tahoma**, but changes to **Calibri** in target document. This happens wether the target doc is XLS or XLSX.

The code to copy is pretty simple and I don't do any formatting after the copy:

```
Set shTb = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(templateSheetName).Copy after:=shTb
Set shBal = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

I can of course write a few lines to apply the right font in the target, but I would like to understand why this happens. Any idea ?

Note: after writing this question, I tried to copy the sheet *manually*, and I get the same issue.

[image]

Comment: In the original document, is the font set to "Calibri" or "Calibri (Body)"?

Comment: in original, it's Tahoma (Body)

Comment: That (body) means that the font is not actually set to Tahoma. It's set to "use document default body font"

Comment: @GregViers Can you make this a reply pls ? It helped me solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original, if it says Tahoma (body), that means it is not really set to Tahoma. Rather the "(body)" indicates that the program will apply the default font for the document. So when you copy it to a new book, it uses the default for that book.

To resolve this, you either need to:

- Change it to just "Tahoma" in the original before you copy it

  Or
- change it after you copy it

Or

- change the default of the new book for body to Tahoma.